# Open app in new window

Tags: macos, mac

I have recently switched to Mac so I'm still getting working out all the keyboard shortcuts I am accustomed to with my previous OS (Windows).

On windows I use to quickly open new explorer windows by simply clicking on a explorer tab while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Is there something similar to this on Mac OS? I already know of <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for new windows but that's only if I'm in the finder app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of solutions to this. Unfortunately, they use 3rd party programs that both cost money, but I feel they both are worth it (for this, and many other reasons).

Firstly, [hyperdock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/) enhances the dock with many new features:

> HyperDock adds long awaited features to your Dock: Select individual application windows just by moving the mouse on a dock item, use mouse clicks to quickly open new windows and many more. *(from the website)*

The mouse clicks feature is what you need. You can easily replicate the windows 7 feature by adding a New Window Action for any dock item when <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> click is used. Note that this will work for most apps. Eg with firefox/chrome it will open a new browser window.

This program costs $10. Make sure you buy the non-app store version though, as the app store version doesn't have this feature!

---

An other solution is [Total Finder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/). This adds a lot of features to finder, such as tabbed browsing and cut and paste. It also has a visor feature - this lets you show and hide a special finder window with a single hotkey. I can't live without this now.

This program costs $18

---

There are likely other free solutions to this as well, but I haven't looked for them yet.